# Which activations are stored until backpropagation in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to tell, which forward-pass activations will be cached/saved until backpropagation in Tensorflow?

I am trying to identify which layers have the greatest memory impact and limit my training capacity.

Comment: As far as I know in gradient descent ( backpropogation ), we require the activations of all the hidden layers to calculate the gradients. TensorFlow also stored the activations for each layer so as to use them while back propagation.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal thank you for your insight. This is close to what I suspected. How do you think, does the same hold for activation/max_pooling/batch_norm layers or only for layers with matrix multiplications?